# Visual Studio Code Version 1.15 - Google Maps API not working, red ampersand

Tags: javascript, google-maps, visual-studio-code

So I'm currently trying to get a map on my webpage, and have the correct code in the editor, however where I src my google and plug in my API key the ampersand after my key is red. I don't know if this is causing the problem or not, but the map isn't showing up.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

```
    <div id="map">
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvTry6RgHatGai_J7kt66sA5chXzhkghY&callback=initMap">
  </script>

  </div>
```

[image: Red Ampersand]

Comment: Not getting the red ampersand in VSCode...

Comment: Check edit posted a picture

Comment: Any error when you hover over it?

Comment: No, I don't even know if this is the problem, I just know a map isn't popping up, and the code and key are good. It just seems like that is the only thing out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context is HTML, so to [represent an ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML), use `&amp;`.

Currently you are attempting to denote entity `&callback=initmap` what is invalid one, therefore the ampersand is red.

Comment: I was trying this without the semi colon. Do you see any reason why the map wouldn't be popping up? The &amp; made it not be red, however the map still didn't show up.

Comment: @C2H50H –  without the semicolon the notation is invalid. Could you try to use `&amp;` as expected?

Comment: I'm currently using &amp; and it is no longer red, however the map still isn't being made.

Comment: @C2H50H – did you check for other errors, because the link is delivering the script **js.js**, which seems to be OK to me. Are you able to check whether the script is successfully downloaded and included in the page? If yes, then the problem could be elsewhere – consider issue with ampersand fixed and search for another one.